# Strange Linq to Entities Behavior with AsExpandable()

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6, linqkit

Consider the following `Person` entity:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Using the following `Expression` (constructed using `PredicateBuilder`) as the criteria:

```
var byName = PredicateBuilder.True<Person>().And(x => x.FirstName == "Chaim");
```

When invoked using the following syntax, the generated SQL is fine (includes the `WHERE` statement):

```
ctx.Set<Person>().AsExpandable().Where(x => byName.Invoke(x));
```

However, when invoked using this slightly different syntax, no SQL `WHERE` is involved and the filtering is being done by `Enumerable.Where` instead:

```
ctx.Set<Person>().AsExpandable().Where(byName.Invoke);
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: This is *extremely* dangerous.  I called `Where(expression.Compile())` instead of `Where(x => expression.Invoke(x))`.  Then later, upon tracing our production database for suck, I see `select [every column] from Table`; no where clause.  The former comes right from the docs!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no implicit conversion from a method group to an `Expression` (of a corresponding delegate type).  There *is* an implicit conversion from a method group to a delegate of a matching signature.  Therefore only the `IEnumerable` overload matches.

Of course, that's not to say that you need to use a lambda.  Just write:

```
ctx.Set<Person>().AsExpandable().Where(ByName);
```

Since you're passing in an expression (`ByName` is, after all, an `Expression<Person, bool>` already, which is exactly what `Queryable.Where<Person>` requires) this will evaluate as a query, not in linq to objects.

Comment: Interesting. so you're basically saying that `ByName.Invoke` is `Func<Person, bool>` then only matches `IEnumerable.Where`, while `x => ByName.Invoke(x)` is `Expression<Func<Person, bool>>` then matches `IQueryable.Where`?

Comment: @haim770 `x => ByName.Invoke(x)`, being a lambda, can match *either*.  It can be an expression, or a delegate.  Because of that, both `Queryable.Where` and `Enumerable.Where` are valid options, and it moves on to a betterness algorithm.  `Queryable` wins.  `ByName.Invoke`, being just a method group, like any other method group, is not convertible to an `Expression`, so `Enumerable.Where` is the only possible valid overload.

Comment: I see. choosing the 'better algorithm' is performed at runtime? how?

Comment: @haim770 It's done at compile time.  See the specs on overload resolution for the details.